# WebAPIのレスポンスから任意の要素を取得したい

Tags: python, python3, api, xml

YAHOOショッピングの商品レビュー検索のWebAPIを使ってレビューの本文を抽出したいです。
XMLファイルを読み取るところまでは多分できていますが、実際に本文のみを抽出することができません。
カテゴリーIDは適当です。
/ResultSet/Result/Descriptionのレスポンスフィールドのみを表示したいのです。
このコードだと最後の行でエラーが出現します。

**エラー内容**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(root['./ResultSet/Result/Description'].text)
TypeError: element indices must be integers
```

**プログラム**

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

params = {
    "category_id": "2501"
}

p = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)

u = 'https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/reviewSearch?'
a = 'appid=XXXXXXXXXXXX(自分のID)&'

url = u + a + p

req = urllib.request.Request(url)

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    xml_string = response.read()

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

print(root['./ResultSet/Result/Description'].text)
```

追記・変更
ElementTreeではなくBeautifulSoupをつかうと本文のみ抽出できるようになりましたが、文章の間にというタグがくっついたまま出力されてしまいます。

変更後コード

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

params = {
    "category_id": "2501"
}

p = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)

u = 'https://shopping.yahooapis.jp/ShoppingWebService/V1/reviewSearch?'
a = 'appid=XXXXXXXXXXX&'

url = u + a + p

req = urllib.request.Request(url)

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    xml_string = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string, "xml")
print(soup.find_all("Description"))
```

出力

> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beautifulsoup4のfind_allの次に、各要素のtextアトリビュートを使って文字列を取得すると良いと思います。

```
descriptions = []
for d in soup.find_all("Description"):
    descriptions.append(d.text)

print(descriptions)
```